# Recognize sentence structure in Prolog

Tags: prolog, nlp

I have a situation where I'm reading in three different types of sentences. They will be of one of the following forms:

```
_ is a _
A _ is a _
Is _ a _?
```

I need to be able to recognize which type of sentence was entered and then add to or query my knowledge base.

For example, the user may input:

```
Fido is a dog.
```

I would then add that fact to my knowledge base. The user could then enter:

```
Is Fido a dog?
```

And the program would answer yes. So far my only idea of recognizing the facts is splitting the sentences on spaces and storing them in a list. Then checking to see where the keywords appear in the list. This is not the best solution since it assumes the "_" characters will always be a single word.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: You will need an explicit intermediary level. Like tokens.

Comment: For your basic cases what you suggest will work. The general NLP is quite involved and not a good single question on Stackoverflow.com. In your case, you could read in the sentence, get it into a list of words, then use a DCG or simple predicate to pull out the subject (X) and the object (Y). Have facts in your db like `is_a('Fido', dog).` etc and you'd just check `is_a(X, Y)` after you derived `X` and `Y` from your input.

Comment: @lurker Think that's what I'm going to go with. Something else I've also realized is that I will need to support transitivity. For instance, if Fido is a dog and all dog's are mammals, then Fido should also be added as a mammal. What would be the best way to support this transitive closure?

Comment: I think you can just use `is_a(dog, mammal).` and `is_a('Fido', dog).` and define a predicate not named `is_a/2`, such as, `kind_of(X, Y) :- is_a(X, Y). kind_of(X, Y) :- is_a(X, A), kind_of(A, Y).` Since your `is_a` is hierarchical, not network, you should be safe from infinite recursions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to split an input into a list of tokens,
is to use atomic_list_concat/3. Here is are some example:

```
?- atomic_list_concat(X,' ','Fido is a dog .').
X = ['Fido', is, a, dog, '.'].

?- atomic_list_concat(X,' ','Is Fido a dog ?').
X = ['Is', 'Fido', a, dog, ?].
```

You can then use a DCG to parse sentences, return a parse
tree of the sentence. The simplest is:

```
s(fact(isa(X,Y))) --> [X, is, a, Y, '.'].
s(query(isa(X,Y))) --> ['Is', X, a, Y, '?'].
```

To actually parse use the predicate phrase/2. You can 
then glue everything together by a parse tree interpreter, 
call this predicate handle/1:

```
do(X) :-
   atomic_list_concat(Y,' ',X),
   phrase(s(Z),Y),
   handle(Z).

:- dynamic isa/2.

handle(fact(X)) :- assertz(X), 
    write('Knowledege base extended'), nl.
handle(query(X)) :- 
    (X -> write('Query succeeded'), nl; 
          write('Query failed'), nl).
```

Here is an example run:

```
 ?- do('Is Fido a dog ?').
 Query failed

 ?- do('Fido is a dog .').
 Knowledege base extended

 ?- do('Is Fido a dog ?').
 Query succeeded
```

Bye