# Convert Prolog sentence to query

Tags: prolog

Is there any way to convert a simple sentence like:

```
Is Bob a man?
```

to a Prolog query like:

```
man(Bob).
```

My thought is to take `Bob` and `man` from the input then store them in variables. Then somehow build the query from those variables. Is that possible?

Comment: Very cool question.  Opens a lot of potential NLP (natural language processing) doors.  This site talks about turning sentences into their grammatical breakdowns. http://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/7_2.html  Perhaps you can break your sentences ending with question marks into a tree and go from there

Comment: Didn't you basically already ask this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920816/recognize-sentence-structure-in-prolog)? The answer to your question is, yes, it is possible. I think the next step is to make an attempt at a solution and show what you've tried.